# Create PostgreSQL table specifying different query specification of each unique ID

Tags: postgresql, loops

Following is an example of a data tables for a database.

Encounter table: Columns: encounterid , patientid, admit_date, discharge_date
Patient table: patient_id, unique_patient_id

I have selected a specific group of patients and identified unique ids associated with those patients based on specific criteria, let's say this is encounter 1.

Each of these unique patients has further encounters with the system. I want to collect all of the future encounters past the discharge date but within 1 year from the discharge period.

Lets say my selected ids and dates are listed as following:

```
unique_id date_discharge date_discharge_365
1           d_dt1           f_dt1
2           d_dt2           f_dt2
.            .                .
.            .                .
n            d_dtn           f_dtm
```

How do I select all of the specific encounters for each of those ids from the encounter table based on specific selection criteria for each of the ids?

Comment: You should provide example data for the Encounter table

Comment: @RaymondNijland
 The table is structured as following: 

encounter_id   patient_id    admit_date  discharge_date   _other_variables